# each_with_index_do starting at 1 for index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, iterator

I am using a ruby iterator on a view in a rails app like so:

```
<% (1..@document.data.length).each_with_index do |element, index| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I thought the addition of the 1.. instead of just saying:
 `@document.data`

would get the trick of having the index above start at 1.  But alas, the above code index is still 0 to data.length (-1 effectively).  So what am I doing wrong, i need the index to equal 1-data.length...no clue how to set up the iterator to do this.

Comment: The first index of an array is always going to be `0`.

Comment: The index will always be zero based. Why does it matter?

Comment: @Codejoy - It would be wise to upvote/accept some answers since your question was answered by multiple users.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think maybe you misunderstand `each_with_index`.

`each` will iterate over elements in an array

```
[:a, :b, :c].each do |object|
  puts object
end
```

which outputs;

```
:a
:b
:c
```

`each_with_index` iterates over the elements, and also passes in the index (starting from zero)

```
[:a, :b, :c].each_with_index do |object, index|
  puts "#{object} at index #{index}"
end
```

which outputs

```
:a at index 0
:b at index 1
:c at index 2
```

if you want it 1-indexed then just add 1.

```
[:a, :b, :c].each_with_index do |object, index|
  indexplusone = index + 1
  puts "#{object} at index #{indexplusone}"
end
```

which outputs

```
:a at index 1
:b at index 2
:c at index 3
```

---

if you want to iterate over a subset of an array, then just choose the subset, then iterate over it

```
without_first_element = array[1..-1]

without_first_element.each do |object|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 155):

Unless you're using an older Ruby like 1.8 (I think this was added in 1.9 but I'm not sure), you can use `each.with_index(1)` to get a 1-based enumerator:

In your case it would be like this:

```
<% @document.data.length.each.with_index(1) do |element, index| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Works in Ruby 2.6.4, though I missed the each*.*with and was using an underscore at first.

Answer (score 12):

This may not be exactly the same `each_with_index` method in question, but I think the result may close to something in mod is asking...

```
%w(a b c).each.with_index(1) { |item, index| puts "#{index} - #{item}" }

# 1 - a
# 2 - b
# 3 - c
```

For more information https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index

Answer (score 10):

Use [`Integer#next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-next):

```
[:a, :b, :c].each_with_index do |value, index|
  puts "value: #{value} has index: #{index.next}"
end
```

produces:

```
value: a has index: 1
value: b has index: 2
value: c has index: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as making the index start from 1.  If you want to skip the first item in the array use `next`.

```
<% (1..@document.data.length).each_with_index do |element, index| %>
  next if index == 0
<% end %>
```

Comment: Trivia: Perl has a global variable `$[` you can set to make all array indices start at 1 or any other value. We should be VERY GLAD Ruby does not have this.

Answer (score 1):

An array index is always going to be zero based.

If you want to skip the first element, which it sounds like you do:

```
@document.data[1..-1].each do |data|
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want to start the index from 1, but in ruby arrays goes as 0 base indexes, so the simplest way would be

given `@document.data` is an array

```
index = 1
@document.data.each do |element| 
    #your code
    index += 1
end
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by using the each_with_index method. But added 1 to the index in the code.

```
@someobject.each_with_index do |e, index|
   = index+1
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who came here looking for `each_with_index` starting at an offset - You are looking for `with_index`.

change `each_with_index` to `each.with_index(2)` for starting with index 2